# point of intersection of two lines, one case works another it doesnt

Tags: javascript, algorithm, svg, graph, polygon

I have this code https://codepen.io/octaviandd/pen/dyoaJVZ?editors=0010

Basically a polygon and a line, when I move the mouse and cross the whole polygon, I need to find the intersection between the line and the polygon's lines (just left side and right side of the polygon). I use the same algorithm for both left and right side, for left side it works , for right side it doesnt.

Left side :

```
if (
    (positions.a1x === positions.a2x && positions.a1y === positions.a2y) ||
    (points[0].x === points[6].x && points[0].y === points[6].y)
  ) {
    return false;
  }

  let denominator =
    (points[6].y - points[0].y) * (positions.a2x - positions.a1x) -
    (points[6].x - points[0].x) * (positions.a2y - positions.a1y);

  if (denominator === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  let ua =
    ((points[6].x - points[0].x) * (positions.a1y - points[0].y) -
      (points[6].y - points[0].y) * (positions.a1x - points[0].x)) /
    denominator;
  let ub =
    ((positions.a2x - positions.a1x) * (positions.a1y - points[0].y) -
      (positions.a2y - positions.a1y) * (positions.a1x - points[0].x)) /
    denominator;

  if (ua < 0 || ua > 1 || ub < 0 || ub > 1) {
    return false;
  }

  let x = positions.a1x + ua * (positions.a2x - positions.a1x);
  let y = positions.a1y + ua * (positions.a2y - positions.a1y);
```

Right side:

```
if (
    (positions.a1x === positions.a2x && positions.a1y === positions.a2y) ||
    (points[2].x === points[3].x && points[2].y === points[3].y)
  ) {
    return false;
  }

  let denominator2 =
    (points[3].y - points[2].y) * (positions.a2x - positions.a1x) -
    (points[3].x - points[2].x) * (positions.a2y - positions.a1y);

  if (denominator2 === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  let ua2 =
    ((points[3].x - points[2].x) * (positions.a1y - points[2].y) -
      (points[3].y - points[2].y) * (positions.a1x - points[2].x)) /
    denominator;
  let ub2 =
    ((positions.a2x - positions.a1x) * (positions.a1y - points[2].y) -
      (positions.a2y - positions.a1y) * (positions.a1x - points[2].x)) /
    denominator;

  if (ua2 < 0 || ua2 > 1 || ub2 < 0 || ub2 > 1) {
    return false;
  }

  let x2 = positions.a1x + ua2 * (positions.a2x - positions.a1x);
  let y2 = positions.a1y + ua2 * (positions.a2y - positions.a1y);
```

If I cross the polygon from left to right, the point of collision seems to come inwards, if i go from right to left, the point of collision seems to go outwards; If my line comes from left and goes close to the right side but doesnt touch it, the algorithm still finds somehow a fake collision.

The initial coords for the polygon:

```
    const points = [
      { x: 100, y: 100 },
      { x: 200, y: 50 },
      { x: 300, y: 50 },
      { x: 400, y: 200 },
      { x: 350, y: 250 },
      { x: 200, y: 300 },
      { x: 150, y: 300 }
    ];
```

Any help?

Comment: When you calculate `ua2` and `ub2`, you must divide by `denominator2`, not `denominator`.  To avoid such errors, I suggest that you write a separate function that calculates the intersection istead of duplicating the code with similar parameters in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for exactly the same issue, until I ended up writing my own set of solutions for these kind of problems :

- First you need to know if two segments intersect or not, this function returns true or false :
  https://github.com/NetworkGraphs/graphysics/blob/79f9fe40ed5851867bf49a2eb2c96dcd61ef9dc5/libs/geometry.js#L206
- once you are sure they do, you are protected from division by zero and you can treat them as two lines intersection problem which is relatively simple :
  https://github.com/NetworkGraphs/graphysics/blob/79f9fe40ed5851867bf49a2eb2c96dcd61ef9dc5/libs/geometry.js#L165
- Now to sum it up, if you have a polygone and a line, you can get inspired by this function I have for intersection between a box and a line. I use the angles to check with which side I have to perform the intersection test, but you could use the first profided function to know with which plygon edge you have to perform an intersection test.
  https://github.com/NetworkGraphs/graphysics/blob/79f9fe40ed5851867bf49a2eb2c96dcd61ef9dc5/libs/geometry.js#L122

Note you might have to adjust the epsilon value, as I have set it to 1 for me as one pixel is already too small.

I cannot guarantee that this is the most optimal way in terms of computation efficiency, but what is sure is that they're safe and robust against any division per zero for ll cases, as I perform an epsilon check before any operation leading to a division.

You can see the whole thing running live in this demo where I use it to draw a graph, and I need to find where the arrow of the edge will touch the Vertex Label box.
https://networkgraphs.github.io/graphysics/